# Extremely bizarre code generation in Visual C++, for nearly identical code; 3x speed difference

Tags: c++, performance, visual-c++, code-generation

The code below (reduced from my larger code, after my astonishment at how its speed paled in comparison with that of `std::vector`) has two peculiar features:

- It runs more than **three times faster** when I make a *very* tiny modification to the source code (always compiling it with `/O2` with Visual C++ 2010).

  **Note:** To make this a little more fun, I put a hint for the modification at the end, so you can spend some time figuring out the change yourself. The original code was ~500 lines, so it took me a heck of a lot longer to pin it down, since the fix looks pretty irrelevant to the performance.
- It runs about 20% **faster** with `/MTd` than with `/MT`, *even though the output loop looks the same!!!*

The difference in the assembly code for the tiny-modification case is:

- Loop *without* the modification (~300 ms):

  ```
  00403383  mov         esi,dword ptr [esp+10h] 
  00403387  mov         edx,dword ptr [esp+0Ch] 
  0040338B  mov         dword ptr [edx+esi*4],eax 
  0040338E  add         dword ptr [esp+10h],ecx 
  00403392  add         eax,ecx 
  00403394  cmp         eax,4000000h 
  00403399  jl          main+43h (403383h)
  ```
- Loop *with* `/MTd` (looks identical! but ~270 ms):

  ```
  00407D73  mov         esi,dword ptr [esp+10h] 
  00407D77  mov         edx,dword ptr [esp+0Ch] 
  00407D7B  mov         dword ptr [edx+esi*4],eax 
  00407D7E  add         dword ptr [esp+10h],ecx 
  00407D82  add         eax,ecx 
  00407D84  cmp         eax,4000000h 
  00407D89  jl          main+43h (407D73h)
  ```
- Loop *with* the modification (~100 ms!!):

  ```
  00403361  mov         dword ptr [esi+eax*4],eax 
  00403364  inc         eax  
  00403365  cmp         eax,4000000h 
  0040336A  jl          main+21h (403361h)
  ```

Now my question is, **why** should the changes above have the effects they do? It's completely bizarre!

Especially the first one -- it shouldn't affect anything at all (once you see the difference in the code), and yet it lowers the speed dramatically.

Is there an explanation for this?

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <ctime>
#include <algorithm>
#include <memory>
template<class T, class Allocator = std::allocator<T> >
struct vector : Allocator
{
    T *p;
    size_t n;
    struct scoped
    {
        T *p_;
        size_t n_;
        Allocator &a_;
        ~scoped() { if (p_) { a_.deallocate(p_, n_); } }
        scoped(Allocator &a, size_t n) : a_(a), n_(n), p_(a.allocate(n, 0)) { }
        void swap(T *&p, size_t &n)
        {
            std::swap(p_, p);
            std::swap(n_, n);
        }
    };
    vector(size_t n) : n(0), p(0) { scoped(*this, n).swap(p, n); }
    void push_back(T const &value) { p[n++] = value; }
};
int main()
{
    int const COUNT = 1 << 26;
    vector<int> vect(COUNT);
    clock_t start = clock();
    for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) { vect.push_back(i); }
    printf("time: %d\n", (clock() - start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
}
```

---

#### **Hint (hover your mouse below)**:

> It has to do with the allocator.

#### **Answer**:

> Change `Allocator &a_` to `Allocator a_`.

Comment: What tiny modification? Is this supposed to be a puzzle or a genuine question?

Comment: Regarding the time difference between loop 1 and 2; have you done extensive time measuring and calculated a mean value? (As you probably already know times could vary a lot even for the exact same code from run to run.)

Comment: @ManofOneWay: Yes I have, it's very consistent.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: I just added the answer at the bottom, hover your mouse to see.

Comment: i think it is expectable, that modified loop with 4 instruction takes shorter time than original 7 instructions

Comment: Evidently the compiler is being conservative about possible aliasing but I'm still not sure what your question is really about.

Comment: @CharlesBailey: Well the question would be, aliasing of what? The allocator has no instance fields which need to be read or written to, so what is happening?

Comment: @RenéKolařík: But why should those loops be generated differently? The method call for the allocator doesn't require an instance pointer anyway, so what's the root cause for this difference?

Comment: For some strange reason, if you remove the `std::swap(n_, n);` line, then you always get the fast loop. Also note that in the `vector` constructor you have two variables named `n`: the member and the parameter! That is quite confusing.

Comment: @rodrigo: Great point, sorry. That wasn't intentional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's strange that Allocator& will break the alias chain while Allocator will not.

You can try

```
for(int i=vect.n; i<COUNT;++i){
    ...
}
```

to enforce i and n are synchronized.
This will make vc much easier to optimize.

Comment: Lenx, I'm not sure I follow what you're saying -- how does this explain the issues with the allocators? (Also, this is a bit random, but... do we know each other?!)

Comment: Hi, Mehrdad, nice to meet you here :) Oh, I figure out your question. It's really strange for vc2010. Allocator& makes vc not able to recognize that n is synchronized with i. Maybe you can try:
  for(int i=vect.n; i < COUNT; i++) ...
to see whether it can be optimized correctly.

Comment: Haha great to see you here too! :) That's an amazing find -- I just tried what you mentioned and it improved the time from 270 ms to 180 ms! It's still not the ~90 ms I see, but it's much closer. +1 I would have never thought of this, thanks for pointing it out!

Answer (score 6):

For what it's worth, my speculation for the difference between `/MT` and `/MTd` is that the `/MTd` heap allocation will paint the heap memory for debugging purposes making it more likely to be paged in - that occurs before you start the clock.

If you 'pre-heat' the vector allocation, you get the same numbers for `/MT` and `/MTd`:

```
vector<int> vect(COUNT);

// make sure vect's memory is warmed up
for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) { vect.push_back(i); }
vect.n = 0; // clear the vector

clock_t start = clock();
for (int i = 0; i < COUNT; i++) { vect.push_back(i); }
printf("time: %d\n", (clock() - start) * 1000 / CLOCKS_PER_SEC);
```

Comment: +1 fantastic answer, seems like it's spot-on. Definitely does the trick. :)

Answer (score 0):

emm... It seems that the "fastest" code

```
00403361  mov         dword ptr [esi+eax*4],eax 
00403364  inc         eax  
00403365  cmp         eax,4000000h 
0040336A  jl          main+21h (403361h)
```

is somewhat over-optimized. In this loop, vect.n is ignored at all...
If there was an exception happened in the loop, vect.n will not be updated correctly.

So the answer might be: when you use Allocator, vc figures out that vect.n will be never used again,
so that it can be ignored. It's amazing, but in general it's not so useful and dangerous.